# PowerBi, need to show values for selected customer and values that are for all customers

Tags: powerbi

I'm creating a report that should show prices for items.

Have a table with the price list, a row in the price list can be connected to a specific customer or to "All Customers" The need is to filter on a specific customer then show the lines that are for the "All Customers".

Table Pricelist

| PriceList | ItemNo | Price | Applied to CustomerNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 10 | C123 |
| 2 | 12346 | 11 | All Customers |
| 3 | 12347 | 4 | C124 |
| 1 | 12348 | 8 | C123 |

Table Item

| ItemNo | ItemDesc |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Item 12345 |

Table ItemRef

| ItemNo | Customer | CustomersItemNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | C123 | Item1 |
| 12345 | C124 | 555666 |
| 12346 | C123 | Item2 |
| 12348 | C123 | Item3 |

Table Customers

| CustomerNo | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| C123 | Customer 123 |
| C124 | Customer 124 |

Wanted solution

Select customer C123 in a slicer

I have a table visual that is like this

| ItemNo | Cust.ItemDesc. | Price | Pricelist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Item1 | 10 | 1 |
| 12346 | Item2 | 11 | 2 |
| 12348 | Item3 | 8 | 1 |

Item 12346 is not in a price list connected specific to Customer C123.

Any good solution for that?